# Not authorized for search.asmx web-service?

Tags: sharepoint, search

How can I get authorized to use  ..._vti_bin/search.asmx ?

I manage to set up a service reference to the above web service.

Anonymous access is disabled on the Sharepoint port 80 site.

Here is my code in VS 2010:

```
DocSystemApplication.QueryWebServiceProxy.QueryServiceSoapClient client = new DocSystemApplication.QueryWebServiceProxy.QueryServiceSoapClient();

client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

string queryXML = @" ....  ";

System.Data.DataSet dataset = client.QueryEx(queryXML);
```

This gives the runtime exception:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM'.

A related question is that the examples I find do not seem to use the "QueryServiceSoapClient" but just "QueryService" ?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. // Lars S

Comment: Similar question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608887/sharepoint-web-services-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentic/2609909#2609909

Comment: QueryService - that appears to be the SharePoint 2007 approach... whereas QueryServiceSoapClient is the SharePoint 2010 approach.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself.

In the app.config there is a section `security mode="None"`, 
and on next line... `transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""`

I changed this to `mode="TransportCredentialOnly"` and ...`clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm" realm=""`

and it started working!

We found this suggestion [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19106).