# wcf as windows service fails with error

Tags: wcf

I wrote a self-hosted WCF service. When I run the server and the client, the client connects well. I rewrote the server as a Windows service. Now when I run the server and the client, the server is started, but the client fails upon request method with the error

**The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was**

Windows service is registered as LocalSystem. Server config:-

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" name="UCSService.UCSModule">
          <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="UCSService.IUCSModule">
          </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9000/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                  maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
              <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Client config:-

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:00:30" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    messageEncoding="Text">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.101.123:9000/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" contract="UCSModuleClient.IUCSModule"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_UCSModule" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

As I understand it, the main problem is that the server has become the service, but how to solve the problem I do not know. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Follow this link i hope it will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570108/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-negotiate
http://morrisbahrami.blogspot.com/2011/02/http-request-is-unauthorized-with.html

Comment: Well, I tried this (the one about IIS) but I still have the error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use google in the following fashion: https://www.google.com.bh/search?q=The+HTTP+request+is+unauthorized+with+client+authentication+scheme+%27Negotiate%27.&oq=The+HTTP+request+is+unauthorized+with+client+authentication+scheme+%27Negotiate%27.&aqs=chrome..69i57.384j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Possible solution: Try to run the service with the user `Administrator`

Comment: My account has Administrator rights and including Administrators group. And Google search, of course I used it, but the most decisions about NTLM or IIS.

Comment: @VJS - Your account may have administrator rights, but does the account *running* the service have them?

Comment: I set that the service is running from Administrator account and have the same error. Also I tried fill ClientCredentials.UserName and ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential with the same data on client side.