# WCF - MessageSecurityException-Request forbidden with client authentication scheme Ntlm

Tags: wcf, ntlm

we have just moved app to windows server 2022. Its dot net based web application and a WCF service is hosted under it.

This service has been used by multiple clients within ORG. It was working in previous servers (windows server 2012). In the new servers there is intermittent error

"System. ServiceModel.Security. MessageSecurityException: The HIT request was forbidden with client authentication scheme "Ntlm'.System.Net. WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

We are using ClientCredentialType as ntlm at both sides Client/WCF as sever. Consider a consuming client is also a dot net console app. It works 7 out of 10 times, but fails for 3 times.
Anything/Setting we would need to do on new server or anything ?

Thanks in advance.

I tried from different clients, same issue

Comment: You can refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570108/the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authentication-scheme-negotiate) for more details. New versions of windows are all starting with Kerberos. Use Kerberos if you can.