# SSRS Web Service access exception - 401 Unauthorized scheme 'Ntlm'

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I already spent a work day long for the following .NET framework 4.0 exception. I have researched solutions online, but I haven't found out a working one. 
Please help and thanks in advance.

My asp.net web application **runs OK on my local PC environment** that has both IIS 8.0 and local SQL Server 2012 instance, but the
exception rises **when I deployed it to the web server** that has both IIS 8.0 and SQL Server 2012 instance.

The excetpion:

```
Stack Trace: 

[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8527180
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +237

[MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +14539490
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +622
   MyAspNetSolution.Services.ReportService2010.ReportingService2010Soap.ListChildren(ListChildrenRequest request) +0
   MyAspNetSolution.Services.ReportService2010.ReportingService2010SoapClient.MyAspNetSolution.Services.ReportService2010.ReportingService2010Soap.ListChildren(ListChildrenRequest request) +102
   MyAspNetSolution.Services.ReportService2010.ReportingService2010SoapClient.ListChildren(TrustedUserHeader TrustedUserHeader, String ItemPath, Boolean Recursive, CatalogItem[]& CatalogItems) +220
   MyAspNetSolution.Services.ReportServerInfoService.ListReportCollection(String itemPath, Boolean recursive) +653
   MyAspNetSolution.AspxPageListAllReportsOnSSRS.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +151
   ....  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18034
```

Details/My story:

I have an asp.net web form application that has a web reference to and consumes the SOAP web service of SQL Server 2012 Reporting Service (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee640743.aspx).
My asp.net web form solution named "MyAspNetSolution" is developed with VS 2012 / .NET framework 4.5, and a local enterprise-edition SQL Server 2012. The solution contains a web form application project 
, and other custom class library projects. One of those class library projects is a class library project named "MyAspNetSolution.Services" that has web reference to 
and consumes the SSRS SOAP web service like:

```
...
using MyAspNetSolution.Services.ReportService2010;
using System.Net;
...

namespace MyAspNetSolution.Services
{
    public class ReportServerInfoService
    {
            public CatalogItem[] ListReportCollection(string itemPath, bool recursive)
            {
            CatalogItem[] reportCollection = {};

            try
            {
                ReportService2010.ReportingService2010SoapClient client = new ReportService2010.ReportingService2010SoapClient();
                client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

                client.Open();
                TrustedUserHeader t = new TrustedUserHeader();

                try
                {
                    // I need to list of children of a specified folder.
                    client.ListChildren(t, itemPath, recursive, out reportCollection); // see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listchildren.aspx
                }
                catch (SoapException ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error("ReportServerManagementService--" + ex);
                }
            }
            catch (SoapException ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("ReportServerManagementService--" + ex);
            }

            return reportCollection;
           }
    }
}
```

And the section for the end point, bindings and othes of the SOAP web service of SQL Server 2012 Reporting Service in my web application project **Web.config** looks like:

```
...
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ReportingService2010Soap">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://my-pc-network-domain-or-server-domain/ReportServer_SQL2012/ReportService2010.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ReportingService2010Soap" contract="ReportService2010.ReportingService2010Soap" name="ReportingService2010Soap"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
...
```

P/S:

I also looked at the following thread (for SharePoint client development), the codes are the same as what I am developing (for SSRS client development) but working on my local PC environment, but not on the web server.

[Sharepoint web services -- The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608887/sharepoint-web-services-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client-authenti)

or another resource:

http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2012/05/accessing-report-server-using-report.html

Answer (score 1):

You should try NetworkCredentials and pass them to the client. If you still get error then place this in your wcf config file :

```
<identity>
    <servicePrincipalName value=""/>
</identity>
```

Thanks

Comment: Adding this [identity element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/identity) as a child of the endpoint element resolved the error for me. Thank you